# Upgrading/downgrading recurring digital service plans with Commerce License

Tags: commerce

I've set a stock Drupal 7 website using the minimal installation profile and configured the Commerce License Billing module to take care of monthly, quarterly and yearly recurring subscription plans. However, it is quite confusing how to make possible for the end-users to upgrade or downgrade to/from other plans.

All subscription plans should be prepaid and be upgradable and downgradable at any moment end-user wants, so should also be automatically calculated on pro-rated basis. Trying many different settings per https://www.drupal.org/node/2127603 doesn't help at all:

- editing currently recurring orders won't work as every new edit is saved as just a revision and doesn't effect the amount charged next time - it doesn't change.
- adding a new line item (upgraded or downgraded plan) to the last order (with Recurring: Open status) doesn't save.

Is it possible at all to setup a Drupal Commerce site which would allow upgrade and downgrade recurring plans using already existing contributed modules?

Or additional custom coding is required? And if so then why the https://www.drupal.org/node/2127603 page lists different billing types? Are they indeed available without additional custom solutions?

Comment: I answered you on drupal.org, although the question is a good one. Prepaid and postpaid are available when you configure products. Make sure you have added a billing cycle type in the settings. Metered billing is not available through the UI; you have to write code for that. Upgrading/downgrading requires code, as far as I know. I'm currently working on an implementation of that, so I'll try to write an answer when done.

Comment: @wizonesolutions any updates on this?

Comment: I did get it all working and just haven't gotten around to documenting it.