# How to properly save the commerce_license entity?

Tags: commerce

Unfortunately, [Upgrading/downgrading recurring digital service plans with Commerce License](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/183503/upgrading-downgrading-recurring-digital-service-plans-with-commerce-license) asked two years ago didn't provide any specific solution, so here is another approach.

On https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_license_billing/issues/2630196 @wizonesolutions says:

> you would just make your own upgrade/downgrade form. Load the user's
>   license, and change the product_id. CL and CLB will then automatically
>   notice the plan change and adjust things accordingly when you save the
>   license.

I've loaded user's license and changed the product id with the following code:

```
$entity = entity_load('commerce_license', array($license_id));
$entity[$license_id]->product_id='32';
```

but it's not clear how to save the license. Using `entity_save('commerce_license', $entity);` is giving the error:

```
EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type commerce_license. in entity_extract_ids() (line 7929 of /home/domain/public_html/includes/common.inc).
```

Could anyone guide me how to take this further, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely you mean:

```
entity_save('commerce_license', $entity[$license_id]);
```

Otherwise you’re trying to save an array as an entity, which wouldn’t work.